# Why does RMagick fail with Symbol not found LoadError when starting rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rmagick

When I try to start "rails s" I get the following error:

```
/Users/asciiman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/rmagick.rb:11:in `require': dlopen(/Users/asciiman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/RMagick2.bundle, 9): Symbol not found: _AdaptiveBlurImage (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/asciiman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/RMagick2.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/asciiman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/RMagick2.bundle - /Users/asciiman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/RMagick2.bundle
    from /Users/asciiman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/rmagick.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/asciiman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /Users/asciiman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/asciiman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /Users/asciiman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from /Users/asciiman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /Users/asciiman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /Users/asciiman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /Users/asciiman/Documents/Consulting/OneTaste/omhub/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/asciiman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /Users/asciiman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/asciiman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /Users/asciiman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I'm running OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.5.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling imagemagick and rmagick and still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you did not installed dependencies. Try installing dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get install libmagick9-dev
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
```

I don't that this packages will work in mac, but it works in linux machine.

Comment: This is what brew returns; Warning: No available formula with the name "libmagickwand". Did you mean libmagic?